# Testing custom A-Frame events when using React and aframe-react

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, aframe

In [MathworldVR](https://github.com/michaltakac/mathworldvr) project (https://github.com/michaltakac/mathworldvr) I'm using `aframe-super-hands-component` which fires `'hover-start'` and `'hover-end'` events when user hits/leaves the entity with VR hand controllers. Everything is working as expected.

But how can I call these events from within tests? I cannot simulate those with `TestUtils` from `react-dom/test-utils` when A-Frame entity is rendered with `Enzyme`'s `shallow`, `react-test-renderer`'s `renderer` or Jest, since it only can simulate [traditional React events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#ui-events).

CalcButton component code:

```js
import 'aframe'
import 'super-hands'
import React from 'react'
import { Entity } from 'aframe-react'

export default class CalcButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      depth: 0.02,
      opacity: 1,
    }

    this.startIntersection = this.startIntersection.bind(this)
    this.endIntersection = this.endIntersection.bind(this)
  }

  startIntersection() {
    this.setState({ depth: 0, opacity: 0.2 })
  }

  endIntersection() {
    this.setState({ depth: 0.02, opacity: 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { depth, opacity } = this.state
    return (
      <Entity
        className="interactive"
        geometry={{ primitive: 'box', height: 1, width: 1, depth }}
        material={{ shader: 'flat', side: 'double', color: 'green', opacity }}
        scale={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5 }}
        position={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5, z: 0.5 }}
        hoverable
        events={{
          'hover-start': this.startIntersection,
          'hover-end': this.endIntersection,
        }}
      >
        <Entity text="Test button" />
      </Entity>
    )
  }
}
```

Proposed CalcButton test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import CalcButton from '.'

jest.mock('react-dom')

describe('CalcButton', () => {
  it('simulates hover-start event', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CalcButton />)
    // TODO: Somehow figure out how to simulate event and
    // check if <a-entity> has a geometry.opacity equal to 0.2
  })
})
```

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/tonyhb/redux-ui may be the solution - with this approach I could extract everything into Redux and test it nicely, functional style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For actual browser testing, I would use Karma Test Runner. Check out aframe-react's test harness: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-react/tree/master/tests/browser. There are React tests which test React rendering and React-level stuff, and *browser* tests which test full integration including events.